# Receive HTTP request with Variable, Query BQ and Return Response

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm looking to create a Cloud Function in GCP that receives a HTTP request with parameters, takes the parameters and passes them to Bigquery within SQL statement and returns a result that I can pass back to website.

I am very new at this and I am not an engineer by any stretch. I have got to the point where my Cloud Function deploys correctly and I receive a response "OK" within the browser

When I hit it but can't get the values returned from `BQ` to show on browser.

Here's my function so far and thanks for any help in advance.

```php
import google.cloud.bigquery

def audience(QUERY):
   # BQ Query to get add to cart sessions
   QUERY = """select 
   visitId,
from bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801
limit 10;
return QUERY"""

print(audience)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a Cloud Function that runs exactly the query that you mention on your post. Nonetheless, it could be adapted to any other query very easily according to your needs. You basically need to follow this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/first-python) in order to deploy the function and get a basic understanding as to how to query data using the [Client Library for BigQuery](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/usage/queries.html).

Here is the summary of what you need to do:

1. Create a folder (e.g. `cloudfunctionsexample`) and use `cd [FOLDERNAME e.g. cloudfunctionsexample]` to get inside the folder and inside the folder create two files: `main.py` and `requirements.txt`.

a. main.py :

```
from flask import escape
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()

def bigquery_example(request):

    request_json = request.get_json(silent=True)
    request_args = request.args

    #Check if request have all the correct parameters to run the query
    if request_json and 'column' in request_json:
        column = request_json['column']
    elif request_args and 'column' in request_args:
        column = request_args['column']
    else:
        return('You are missing the column parameter on the request.')

    if request_json and 'name' in request_json:
        name = request_json['name']
    elif request_args and 'name' in request_args:
        name = request_args['name']
    else:
        return('You are missing the name of the dataset parameter on the request.')

    if request_json and 'limit' in request_json:
        limit = request_json['limit']
    elif request_args and 'limit' in request_args:
        limit = request_args['limit']
    else:
        return('You are missing the limit parameter on the request.')

    #Construct the query based on the parameters
    QUERY = ('SELECT '+column+' FROM `'+name+'` LIMIT '+limit)
    #print(QUERY)

    try:
        query_job = client.query(QUERY)  # API request
        rows = query_job.result()  # Waits for query to finish
        # Create a list and make the results HTML compatible to be able to be displayed on the browser.
        row_list = []
        for row in rows:
            row_list.append(str(row[column]))
        return("<p>" + "</p><p>".join(row_list) + "</p>")
    except e:
        return(e)
```

b. requirements.txt :

```
flask
google-cloud-bigquery
```

2. (Assuming you have the [Cloud SDK installed](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/install#installation_options)) and that your make sure that the [App Engine default service account](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/service-account) (which is the default account used by Cloud Functions) has the Editor role assigned run the following  command to deploy the function on your project:

```
gcloud functions deploy bigquery_http_example --runtime python37 --trigger-http --allow-unauthenticated --entry-point=bigquery_example --timeout=540
```

3. Get the Cloud Function URL and use either the curl command to make a POST request or simply add the parameters to the Cloud Function URL to make an HTTP request to the Cloud Function endpoint and see the results directly on your browser.

a. curl :

```
curl -X POST https://[REGION-FUNCTIONS_PROJECT_ID].cloudfunctions.net/bigquery_http_example -H "Content-Type:application/json"  -d '{"column":"visitId","name":"bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801","limit":"10"}'
```

b. Cloud Function URL :

```
https://[REGION-FUNCTIONS_PROJECT_ID].cloudfunctions.net/bigquery_http_example?column=visitId&name=bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801&limit=10
```