# How to check whether data exists in specific column on BigQuery with Flask?

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, flask, google-bigquery

I've been making api with Flask that receives a HTTP request with parameters(luid), takes the parameters and passes them to Bigquery within SQL statement and if the record of luid has data in cv_date column, it returns True. However, when I tried sending request in order to this api with luids that really exists in BigQuery table and does not exists in there , I accepted True from both of them . I want to make it to return False , if it takes luid parameter that doesn't exist in BigQuery. It seems try and exception don't work well . Could anyone give me idea ?? I'm so sorry for my poor code . If there is lack of any info , plese let me know . Thank you so much .

besides, I have already set export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = Json.file and assign IAM to this service account. I succeeded in sending SQL to BigQuery by gcloud app logs tail -s test.

The sites that I referred are below  https://blog.morizyun.com/python/library-bigquery-google-cloud.html
[Receive HTTP request with Variable, Query BQ and Return Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62336680/receive-http-request-with-variable-query-bq-and-return-response)

```
/home/user/api_dev/main.py

from flask import Flask, request
from google.cloud import bigquery


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def get_request():
    # luid = request.args.get('luid') or ''
    client = bigquery.Client()
    query = """SELECT EXISTS(SELECT cv_date
FROM `test-266110.conversion_log.conversion_log_2020*`
WHERE luid = `test-266110.conversion_log.conversion_log_2020*`.luid limit 1000)"""

    try:
        query_job = client.query(query)
        is_exist = len(list(query_job.result())) >= 1
        return "True"
    except:
        return "False"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

```
BigQuery 

luid | pgid | cv_date | orderid 
Uxxxx| 1111 | 2020-08-01| 2222　if this luid, it returns True 
Uxxxx| 2222 | 　　　　　|        if this luid, it returns False
```

Comment: @Soumendra Mishra thank you . I edited it  and made it more clear .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you perform a SELECT that does not match any entry in the DB, no error is thrown, therefore your `except:` is not executed. Your code returns `False`, only if an exception is thrown from your `try:` section.

Your logic seems correct: `is_exist` shall be initialized with the `True` or `False` value returned by the `>=` operator. You just need to return that value instead of always returning `True`. More over, you can keep the `except:` and assume that no entry matched the select statement if an exception is thrown in the process:

```
[...]
    try:
        query_job = client.query(query)
        is_exist = len(list(query_job.result())) >= 1
        return str(is_exist)
    except:
        return False
[...]
```

Comment: thank you so much .  I replaced return "True" for return is_exist ,but I got following error . It

The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a bool.

Comment: I am edited the answer. You can used the `str()` to convert True into "True"

Comment: It works . thanks so much for your explanation ! I understand try and exception . I will try to edit my code to work as my expectation.

Comment: Glad I could help. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: Another way: `query_job.result()` has a attribute called `total_rows`. You can check if this is 0 (doesn't exist)