# Is it possible to put EXECUTE IMMEDIATE and USING into Variable in Python

Tags: sql, python-3.x, flask, google-bigquery

This is a continuous of previous post .
[How to get result from BigQuery based on user input parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63609115/how-to-get-result-from-bigquery-based-on-user-input-parameters) .
I tried to use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE and USING as these article say.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries
https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-dynamic-sql-in-bigquery-8c04dcc0f0de
But when I run the sql , I got syntax error . I'd like to get my sql checked . I guess this error is caused by the line breaks but I want to do that for the readability . Sorry for my poor coding skill . Could you give me advice ??
I'm little bit worry about BigQuery doesn't support dynamic parameter in Python. Because the article above seems to use these statement in Console not in Python .

```
The error 

 File "/srv/main.py", line 14      SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

```
SQL

query = """EXECUTE IMMEDIATE format("""
    SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1
    FROM `test-266778.conversion_log.conversion_log_2020*` as p
    WHERE p.luid = @request_luid AND orderid != '' limit 1000)""")"""
    USING "request_luid" as request_luid;
```

```
/home/user/api_dev/main.py

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from google.cloud import bigquery


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def get_request():
    request_luid = request.args.get('luid') or ''
    client = bigquery.Client()

    query = """EXECUTE IMMEDIATE format("""
    SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1
    FROM `test-266778.conversion_log.conversion_log_2020*` as p
    WHERE p.luid = @request_luid AND orderid != '' limit 1000)""")"""
    USING "request_luid" as request_luid;

    job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(
    query_parameters=[
        bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter("request_luid", "STRING", request_luid)
    ]
    )

    query_job = client.query(query, job_config=job_config)
    query_res = query_job.result()
    first_row = next(iter(query_job.result()))
    for row in query_res:
        return str(row)
        #return jsonify({request_luid:query_res.total_rows})


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def get_request():
    request_luid = request.args.get("luid") or ""
    client = bigquery.Client()

    query = """SELECT EXISTS(
                    SELECT 1
                    FROM `test-266778.conversion_log.conversion_log_2020*` as p
                    WHERE p.luid = {} 
                    AND p.orderid is not null limit 1000)""".format(request_luid)

    query_job = client.query(query)
    query_res = query_job.result()
    first_row = next(iter(query_job.result()))
    for row in query_res:
        return str(row)
```

> Notes: If the `luid` is non-numeric, then use '{}'.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
  """SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM `test-266778.conversion_log.conversion_log_2020*` WHERE luid = ? AND orderid is not null limit 1000)"""
USING
  "string-value";
```

> For numeric input value, don't use double quotes

Comment: Thank you so much . This sql seems no problem in my editor . but I got error by running it . 
【the query must be wrapped with additional parentheses to make it a scalar subquery expression】
Do you have any idea ??

Comment: Thank you so much . I tried it and I corrected indentations but error is still there  "400 Syntax error: Unexpected keyword SELECT at [1:19]". I've been thinking we can not use global variables in BigQuery SQL with Python and there is no way to use  ""EXECUTE IMMEDIATE SELECT EXISTS"".

Comment: I have added a new answer !

Comment: Sensei .... it did work !! Thank you so much ! ! I really appreciate it!!

Comment: Please consider voting up the answer if it helped !